# Gulp - minify without creating random string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I use "gulp build" to generate a single .js file from a set of .js files (angular code).

It is creating file like "app-randomstring.js" but I want it to be "app.js", how to do that ?

## gulpfile.js:

/**
     *  Welcome to your gulpfile!
     *  The gulp tasks are splitted in several files in the gulp directory
     *  because putting all here was really too long
     */

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrench = require('wrench');

/**
 *  This will load all js or coffee files in the gulp directory
 *  in order to load all gulp tasks
 */
wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});


/**
 *  Default task clean temporaries directories and launch the
 *  main optimization build task
 */
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

Comment: What minifier are you using, what does your gulp file look like?

Comment: put your gulp file here please

Comment: Yep, well, we kinda need to see the `'build'` task.... how can you hope for us to help you fix the problem if you don't show it us?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),

gulp.task('build-js', [], function () {
    jslibs = ['path/to/file.js', 'path/to/file2.js'];
    return gulp.src(jslibs)
        .pipe(concat('all.min.js')) // the name you want
        .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('output/path/js/'))
});
```